# How To Select Between 2 Month and Year in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

How to select data between `11-2017` AND `02-2018`?

I did this SQL:

```
SELECT COUNT(tbl_data.avg)
FROM tbl_data
INNER JOIN tbl_one ON tbl_one.idx = tbl_data.idx
WHERE tbl_data.download_date
BETWEEN (MONTH(tbl_data.download_date) = (MONTH(tbl_one.dt) AND YEAR(tbl_data.download_date) = YEAR(tbl_one.dt))
AND (MONTH(tbl_data.download_date) = MONTH(NOW()) AND 
YEAR(tbl_data.download_date) = YEAR(NOW()))
```

but showed ZERO result. How to do that? Thanks before

P.s. : the type of field `download_date` is DATE (YYYY-MM-DD)

Comment: don't complicate it..just use `download_date >= '2017-11-01' and download_date < '2018-03-01'`

Comment: You're not possibly using MySQL and SQL Server at the same time. They're two far different DBMSs. Please use **only** the one that actually applies to your question instead of just randomly adding those that seem similar.

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala see my updated question sir. I want to compare with another field from other table

Comment: whats `<?php function to get now month ?>` and `<?php function to get now year ?>` suppose to mean ?

Comment: @rtfm I did it in my PHP file

Answer (score 0):

So I've found how to make it happen. I just use this SQL command `EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM mytable.date)`. And my sampe query would be like this:

```
SELECT a.id, b.user_name
FROM a
INNER JOIN b
    ON a.id = b.id
WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM a.dl_date) >= EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM b.up_date)
    AND EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM a.dl_date) <= EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM NOW())
```